# two action in one command button in jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf, action

Can i call two action in one button like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="Add"   
            onPointClick="errorMessage();"
                    action="#{restaurant.submitInfo}"
                    />
```

`errorMessage()` is a js function.
I did and it wasn't call `errorMessage()` function. I don't know why. Thank for helping

Comment: Where did you learn about the `onPointClick` attribute? I'm not seeing that anywhere in the tag documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html Why exactly did you think that it would end up in JSF-generated HTML output and that it would be invoked by the webbrowser?

Comment: @BalusC I'm a beginner, so i'm sorry because my mistake, can you tell me how can i do to call 2 function in one h:button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the idea you meant benind "call two actions", but the first thing to be stated is that [`<h:commandButton>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html) doesn't provide for `onPointClick` attribute.

So, if you want to call several **client-side functions**, just call one function and let it handle the number of other calls you want.

On the other hand, if you want to make calls to **several server-side methods**, just add any number of actionlistener methods by nesting `<f:actionListener>` tags, or specifying one actionlistener method in `actionListener` attribute. Alternatively, you could call other related methods in your action method.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is no Javascript Event named `onPointClick` associated with `h:commandButton`.
See the Tag Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html).